# Distance Converter for inches, feet, and yards in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, units-of-measurement

I am completely new to programming, so this is probably a silly question with a simple answer. My application allows users to type a number, select what unit of measurement they are using, select what unit of measurement they what to convert to and convert it.

I have one error in the last line of code that is keeping it from working: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. Can someone please help?

Here's the code:

```
   private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fromDistance;
        int toDistance;

        fromDistance = int.Parse(distanceInput.Text);
        string measureInput = fromList.Items[fromList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string measureOutput = toList.Items[toList.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        switch (measureInput)
        {
            case "Yards":
                switch (measureOutput)
                {
                    case "Yards":
                        toDistance = fromDistance;
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        toDistance = fromDistance * 3;
                        break;
                    case "Foot":
                        toDistance = fromDistance * 3 * 12;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "Feet":
                switch (measureOutput)
                {
                    case "Feet":
                        toDistance = fromDistance;
                        break;
                    case "Yards":
                        toDistance = fromDistance / 3;
                        break;
                    case "Foot":
                        toDistance = fromDistance * 12;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "Foot":
                switch (measureOutput)
                {
                    case "Foot":
                        toDistance = fromDistance;
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        toDistance = fromDistance / 12;
                        break;
                    case "Yards":
                        toDistance = fromDistance / (3 * 12);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        distanceOutput.Text = toDistance;
    }
```

Comment: The error message says: "An Integer was found where a String was expected. However, there is no automatic conversion possible from an Integer to a String". Thus, it's up to the code to manually supply such conversions. Given an Integer, how can a String representing it be obtained?

Comment: I think you've typed Foot where you meant Inches.

Comment: Thank you guys. Like I said, I am new to programming so I am not sure what I'm suppose to do to turn the representation of an integer into an actual integer? And yes, I mean to change 'foot' to 'inches' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString();
```

Looks like you might be used to dynamically typed languages? An int is stored in binary representation, and can represent many different values. .ToString() converts to the most common representation.

BTW you should probably not use an integer for your calculated value type, as you'll throw away fractional numbers. Use a double or float, and use Math.Round(number, decimalPoints) .

Comment: Thank you for the reply zenith. I tried distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString(); and now it says "Use of unassigned local variable." Can you tell me what that means?

Comment: @zenith The compiler is telling you that your logic has a path where toDistance will never be assigned a value.  You can see that it is possible that none of your case statements will ever be executed if measureInput or measureOutput has bad values.  If you're confident that the values are always going to be limited to what your checking in your case statements, then you can simply initialize toDistance to 0 when it is declared at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Ah Yes!! I declared toDistance = 0 and it worked!!! Thank you very much Byron Lo!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the input/output strings to conversion numbers by using an enum.  This has the advantage of greatly simplifying your code, as well.  You must, however, make sure  the strings in your list exactly match the names in your enum.  This simple algorithm will convert from any input to any output.

```
    enum Conversions
    {
        Inches = 1,
        Feet = 12,
        Yards = 36
    }

   private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fromDistance = 0;
        int toDistance = 0;

        fromDistance = int.Parse(distanceInput.Text);

        Conversions measureinput = ((Conversions)Enum.Parse(typeof(Conversions), fromList.Items[fromList.SelectedIndex].ToString());

        Conversions measureoutput = (Conversions)Enum.Parse(typeof(Conversions), toList.Items[toList.SelectedIndex].ToString());

        toDistance = (fromdistance * (int)measureinput) / (int)measureoutput;

        distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString()+ " " + Enum.GetName(typeof(Conversions), measureoutput);
    }
```